# Error while trying to compile ccny_vision package

Tags: rviz, ar-pose

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I´m trying to compile this package but I don´t know what´s the problem to not be possible to make ar_single. The terminal shows:

### root@ROS:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/ccny_vision/ar_pose/demo# rosmake ccny_vision
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['ccny_vision']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/viki/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130307-164700
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['ccny_vision'] to:
['ar_pose', 'artoolkit']
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The stack "geometry" was not found. We will assume it is using the new buildsystem and try to continue...
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The stack "robot_model" was not found. We will assume it is using the new buildsystem and try to continue...
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The stack "ros" was not found. We will assume it is using the new buildsystem and try to continue...
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> artoolkit [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< artoolkit [PASS] [ 0.51 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> catkin [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< catkin ROS_NOBUILD in package catkin
No Makefile in package catkin
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genmsg [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package genmsg                                               [ 1 Active 2/46 Complete ]
No Makefile in package genmsg
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> gencpp [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< gencpp ROS_NOBUILD in package gencpp
No Makefile in package gencpp
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genlisp [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genlisp ROS_NOBUILD in package genlisp
No Makefile in package genlisp
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genpy [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genpy ROS_NOBUILD in package genpy
No Makefile in package genpy
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_generation [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_generation ROS_NOBUILD in package message_generation
No Makefile in package message_generation
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common
No Makefile in package cpp_common
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime
No Makefile in package rostime
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits
No Makefile in package roscpp_traits
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization
No Makefile in package roscpp_serialization
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_runtime [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_runtime ROS_NOBUILD in package message_runtime
No Makefile in package message_runtime
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs
No Makefile in package std_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< geometry_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package geometry_msgs
No Makefile in package geometry_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> visualization_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< visualization_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package visualization_msgs
No Makefile in package visualization_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> angles [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles
No Makefile in package angles
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospack [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospack ROS_NOBUILD in package rospack
No Makefile in package rospack
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
No Makefile in package roslib
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit
No Makefile in package rosunit
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole
No Makefile in package rosconsole
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs
No Makefile in package rosgraph_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp
No Makefile in package xmlrpcpp
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp
No Makefile in package roscpp
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph
No Makefile in package rosgraph
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy
No Makefile in package rospy
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosclean [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosclean ROS_NOBUILD in package rosclean
No Makefile in package rosclean
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosmaster [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosmaster ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmaster                                        [ 1 Active 27/46 Complete ]
No Makefile in package rosmaster
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosout ROS_NOBUILD in package rosout
No Makefile in package rosout
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosparam [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosparam ROS_NOBUILD in package rosparam
No Makefile in package rosparam
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslaunch [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslaunch ROS_NOBUILD in package roslaunch
No Makefile in package roslaunch
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostest ROS_NOBUILD in package rostest
No Makefile in package rostest
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_filters ROS_NOBUILD in package message_filters
No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< sensor_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package sensor_msgs
No Makefile in package sensor_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> tf [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf
No Makefile in package tf
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> resource_retriever [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< resource_retriever ROS_NOBUILD in package resource_retriever
No Makefile in package resource_retriever
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> opencv2 [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< opencv2 ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv2
No Makefile in package opencv2
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> console_bridge [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< console_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package console_bridge
No Makefile in package console_bridge
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> class_loader [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< class_loader ROS_NOBUILD in package class_loader
No Makefile in package class_loader
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib
No Makefile in package pluginlib
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> image_transport [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< image_transport ROS_NOBUILD in package image_transport
No Makefile in package image_transport
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> cv_bridge [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< cv_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_bridge
No Makefile in package cv_bridge
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> ar_pose [ make ]
[ rosmake ] All 5 linesar_pose: 1.1 sec ]                                                                  [ 1 Active 42/46 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
CMake Error: The current CMakeCache.txt directory /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/ccny_vision/ar_pose/build/CMakeCache.txt is different than the directory /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/ccny_vision/ar_pose/build where CMakeCache.txt was created. This may result in binaries being created in the wrong place. If you are not sure, reedit the CMakeCache.txt
CMake Error: The source "/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/ccny_vision/ar_pose/CMakeLists.txt" does not match the source "/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/ccny_vision/ar_pose/CMakeLists.txt" used to generate cache.  Re-run cmake with a different source directory.

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package ar_pose written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/viki/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130307-164700/ar_pose/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< ar_pose [FAIL] [ 1.06 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package ar_pose.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 43 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/viki/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130307-164700
root@ROS:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/ccny_vision/ar_pose/demo#

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57426/error-while-trying-to-compile-ccny_vision-package/) by [alonsosjumper](https://answers.ros.org/users/2135/alonsosjumper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2013-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're trying to compile the precompiled binary packages.  You should  not be building in /opt/ros/*  I suggest you take a look at the [basic tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0